# Reading from two files (one raw, one XMP) with ExifTool

Tags: perl, exiftool

I am new to PERL and even newer to ExifTool—and am therefore likely missing something quite basic.

The goal is to read XMP fields from a photo file. Looking at the exiftool documentation on both the ExifTool site and CPAN, I was able to read tagged jpeg and the XMP sidecar files, both without issues.

The problem is when I read from a raw file—which obviously doesn't have custom fields—I would get an error with an uninitialized value. That is to be expected.

So, I want to have code that says "if you read a field/tag from the raw file and it isn't there, look at the associated XMP file, and if that fails, return a blank string."

I therefore tried to open a second instance of ExifTool, such as:

```
my $exifInfo = ImageInfo($filePath);
```

goes to

```
my $exifInfoXMP = ImageInfo($filePathXMP);
```

But that keeps failing. If I read the XMP directly from the get-go, it works just fine, so I am getting the impression that I cannot read two ExifTool structures at the same time (which can't be right; I have to be the error here). The code below works, but I cannot "interleave" the conditionals on the two files. I have to process the raw first, then run a second pass with a new handler for the XMP. Knowing how efficient PERL is, my approach cannot possibly be a good one (even though it does the job).

In particular, there is one line that puzzles me. If I remove it, nothing works. (it should be well marked).

```
$filePath =~ s/$photoExtensions$/.XMP/i;
```

That line essential does the same as reading the XMP from the get-go (not my ideal solution).

Anyone have an idea as to where I am messing up?

Thanks,

Paul

header [EDITED TO SHOW ALL OPTIONS; HAD SHOWN ALL USED IN QUESTION]

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# load standard packages
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
use Image::ExifTool ':Public';

# define proxy for ExifTool
my $exifTool = new Image::ExifTool;
my $exifToolXMP = new Image::ExifTool;

# turn on immediate updates
$|=1;

# common extensions that I want to recognize
my $photoExtensions = "\.(jpg|crw|cr2|cr3|rw2|orf|raw|nef|arw|dng)";
my $imageExtensions = "\.(tiff|tif|psd|png|eps|hdr|exr|svg|gif|afphoto|pdf)";
my $videoExtensions = "\.(flv|vob|ogv|avi|mts|m2ts|mov|qt|wmv|mp4|m4p|m4v|svi|3gp|3g2)";
my $audioExtensions = "\.(aiff|aac|wav|mp3|m4a|m4p|ogg|wma)";
my $appFileExtensions = "\.(on1|cos|cof)";
my $GPSFileExtensions = "\.(gpx|kml|kmz|log)";

# start main program
main();
```

routine in question

```
sub listKeywords { 
    print "Reads and displays file information from certain tags (typically set in Photomechanic):\n";
    print "\t1. Subject\n";
    print "\t2. Hierarchical Subject\n";
    print "\t3. Supplemental Categories\n";
    print "\t4. Label Name 1\n";
    print "\t5. Label Name 2\n";
    print "\t6. Label Name 3\n";
    print "\t7. Label Name 4\n\n";

    print "List Keywords ---\n\tEnter file name (with path) --> ";
    my $filePath = <STDIN>;
    chomp $filePath;
    $filePath =~ s/\\//g;
    $filePath =~ s/\s+$//;


    ########################################################

    # COMMENT OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE AND NOTHING WORKS;
    # $filePathXMP should be defined anyway, which suggests to 
    # me that the second invocation of ImageInfo doesn't actually occur. 
    # But I don't understand why.

    $filePath =~ s/$photoExtensions$/.XMP/i;
    print "\n\n";

    my $filePathXMP = $filePath;
    $filePathXMP =~ s/$photoExtensions$/.XMP/i;  # TO FIX: filename may not have uppercase extension

    # Get Exif information from image file
    my $exifInfo = $exifTool->ImageInfo($filePath);
    #    my $exifInfoXMP = $exifToolXMP->ImageInfo($filePath =~ s/$photoExtensions$/.XMP/gi);
    print "XMP Sidecar: \[$filePathXMP\]\n\n";

    ########################################################


    # Get Specific Tag Value
    my $hierarchicalSubject = $exifTool->GetValue('HierarchicalSubject');
    my $subject = $exifTool->GetValue('Subject');
    my $supplementalCategories = $exifTool->GetValue('SupplementalCategories');
    my $labelName1 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName1');
    my $labelName2 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName2');
    my $labelName3 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName3');
    my $labelName4 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName4');

    my $exifInfo = ImageInfo($filePathXMP);
    if (not defined $hierarchicalSubject) {$hierarchicalSubject = $exifTool->GetValue('HierarchicalSubject');}
    if (not defined $hierarchicalSubject) {$hierarchicalSubject = "";}
    if (not defined $subject) {$subject = $exifTool->GetValue('Subject');}
    if (not defined $subject) {$subject = "";}
    if (not defined $supplementalCategories) {$supplementalCategories = $exifTool->GetValue('SupplementalCategories');}
    if (not defined $supplementalCategories) {$supplementalCategories = "";}
    if (not defined $labelName1) {$labelName1 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName1');}
    if (not defined $labelName1) {$labelName1 = "";}
    if (not defined $labelName2) {$labelName2 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName2');}
    if (not defined $labelName2) {$labelName2 = "";}
    if (not defined $labelName3) {$labelName3 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName3');}
    if (not defined $labelName3) {$labelName3 = "";}
    if (not defined $labelName4) {$labelName4 = $exifTool->GetValue('LabelName4');}
    if (not defined $labelName4) {$labelName4 = "";}

    print "Subject:\n------------------------------\n$subject\n\n";
    print "Hierarchical Subject:\n------------------------------\n$hierarchicalSubject\n\n";
    print "Supplemental Categories:\n------------------------------\n$supplementalCategories\n\n";
    print "Label Name 1:\n------------------------------\n$labelName1\n\n";
    print "Label Name 2:\n------------------------------\n$labelName2\n\n";
    print "Label Name 3:\n------------------------------\n$labelName3\n\n";
    print "Label Name 4:\n------------------------------\n$labelName4\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is incomplete, I have to ask: did you make sure to start your script with the following lines?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Those two lines are *not* there to annoy you, they will protect you from simple mistakes you might have made in your code.

---

IMHO the real problem with your `sub listKeywords()` is the following line:

```perl
my $exifInfo = ImageInfo($filePathXMP);
```

There are two problems here:

1. you redefine the variable `$exifInfo` from a few lines before.
2. you are not using the OO approach for the 2nd image info.

I think what you intended to write was the following line:

```perl
my $exifInfoXMP = $exifToolXMP->ImageInfo($filePathXMP);
```

Comment: Thank you! The core issue was indeed that I was missing an XMP.

Comment: I did have the `use` lines and hadn't shown them in my question; added them in the question for clarity for future readers. The procedural call was indeed a sloppy mistake made while trying to identify the problem. Everything is now OO. Works like a charm. Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated.